# OpenVPN is not masking my public IP address

Tags: windows-8.1, ip, openvpn

I have OpenVPN installed and connecting on my client to my server in ipconfig it shows that my internal IP is the specified one from my server but my public one does not change

ip config output (Hastebin’ed very long): http://hastebin.com/bacemicivu.sm

Server config and client: http://hastebin.com/yokowiyida.vala

Comment: can you show your ipconfig output and your openvpn config?

Answer (score -1):

Your server is setup so that clients will only send traffic intended for the VPN network over the VPN.  To get all of your traffic to go through the VPN you'll need to change a few configuration options, as described in the [OpenVPN HOWTO](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#redirect):

```
push "redirect-gateway def1"
```

Comment: This Still did not make my IP show up as the VPN's

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of `netstat -rn` and the updated OpenVPN config?

Comment: http://hastebin.com/qigutahuto.pas and http://hastebin.com/uxiwajoxak.vala